# SimpleCursorAdapter with JSON data in database?

Tags: java, android, json, adapter

SimpleCursorAdapter is a quick way to pull data off a database and display it. However I also have JSON data stored in the database and want the Adapter to also display data inside the JSON.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        ctx,
        R.layout.list,
        result,
        new String[]{"name", "properties"},              //properties is a JSON string
        new int[]{R.id.entry_title, R.id.properties},
        0
);
```

Is there some way to achieve that, or do I have to create my own adapter for that?

Comment: Personally, I'd migrate the data from a `Cursor` into a set of POJOs (complete with the parsed JSON), then use something like `ArrayAdapter`. Your problem isn't so much the adapter as it is hanging onto the results of parsing the JSON. I don't know how large this JSON is, but parsing it on the main application thread as part of rendering a list may result in dropped frames. In principle, a `ViewBinder` that you attach to the `SimpleCursorAdapter` can get data from the JSON and populate widgets with it, but you don't want to keep re-re-re-re-re-parsing the same JSON strings.